# How am I using less memory with more variables?

Tags: variables, memory

First off, I'm going to acknowledge that this question probably has an answer I could Google, but my pure math background has left me without the proper vocabulary to know what to search.

I'm writing in Go and working on this problem on LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/

I was able to develop a solution by myself; as I usually do, I started looking at how others solved the problem and trying to optimize for time and space. At some point, I got to this.

```
func generateParenthesis(n int) []string {
    
    ans := []string{}
    
    var dfs func([]byte, int, int) 
    dfs = func(path []byte, o, c int) {
        
        if c == n {
            ans = append(ans, string(path))
        }
        
        if o < n {
            dfs(append(path, '('), o + 1, c)
        }
        
        if o > c {
            dfs(append(path, ')'), o, c + 1)
        }
    }
    
    dfs([]byte{}, 0, 0)
    return ans

}
```

LeetCode said this solution took 2.8MB, which is p-88. I kept looking at other solutions that ran with 2.7MB, which is p-100 and eventually got mine there by doing this.

```
func generateParenthesis(n int) []string {
    
    ans := []string{}
    
    var dfs func(*[]string, []byte, int, int, int) 
    dfs = func(ans *[]string, path []byte, o, c, n int) {
        
        if c == n {
            *ans = append(*ans, string(path))
        }
        
        if o < n {
            dfs(ans, append(path, '('), o + 1, c, n)
        }
        
        if o > c {
            dfs(ans, append(path, ')'), o, c + 1, n)
        }
    }
    
    dfs(&ans, []byte{}, 0, 0, n)
    return ans

}
```

The difference in these is so small as to be easy to miss; the recursive `dfs` takes more arguments in the second version. This doesn't make sense from what I know about memory allocation. I would expect that adding more variables to the recursive function means that more memory needs to be allocated each time a call is placed on the stack.

- The second version an additional `int` and an additional pointer.
- LeetCode is probably running on 64-bit hardware, meaning `int`s and pointers each require an additional 64 bits of memory.
- The maximum number of calls to `dfs` on the stack at one time will be `2*n` and `n` can be as high as 8.

That all leads me to the conclusion that the second version should use (64 + 64) * 2 * 8 = 2048 bits more memory (a negligible amount, tbf) but it is somehow using less.

First question: How can that happen?

Second question: Is this possibly specific to Go and/or the compiler being used?

Answer (score 0):

The second version indeed passes more parameters in the stack. Presumably this is not enough to exceed goroutine stack capacity hence doesn’t make a difference. Default goroutine stack size is 8K and grows in large chunks.

On the other hand, the first version captures additional variable in the closure; the variable has to be heap-allocated.

Declaring dfs as a free-standing function will reduce memory usage even further by getting rid of the closure.

Comment: I think I follow. Are you saying that the closure created by the first version has to be put on the heap, which effectively copies everything from the stack to the heap?

That puts me on another line of questions...
If the closure is getting copied to the heap, does that happen for every call of dfs?
If it doesn't happen for every call of dfs, does that mean the first version scales better as the stack depth grows?

Comment: The closure itself is heap-allocated. Every variable from the outer scope referenced by the function has to be heap allocated as well. The reason is simple: if captured variables were allocated on the stack, and the outter function returned, they would have ceased to exist, breaking the closure that could be still live. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/go-internals-capturing-loop-variables-in-closures/

Comment: To your second question. Calling a closure doesn’t do extra work compared to regular function calls, apart from receiving a single extra hidden parameter. The heavy lifting happens once when the closure is instantiated (dfs assignment). So indeed if by capturing the number of arguments was reduced and the recursion is deep there’s going to be some win. But honestly, I don’t think these micro optimizations should be applied to leetcode problems, better focus on algorithmic improvements.